# Отправка данных при нажатии на Enter

Tags: ajax, javascript

Вот эта кнопка служит для отправки данных через ajax.

```
<button class="main" style="float: left;" id="send" name="button" value="Post">Написать</button>
```

Как при нажатии на Enter производить те же действия?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй поиграть с событиями `html`

- `onkeydown` - событие на нажатие клавиши.
- `onkeyup` - событие на отпускание клавиши.

Из них попробуй достать код символа, `enter` - это, кажется, 13.

Answer (score 1):

Если кнопка в форме, можно изменить кнопку

```
<input type="submit" class="main" value="Написать" />
```

Если нужно просто отработать нажатие Enter

```
$(window).keydown(function(e) {
   if (e.which == 13) {
      sendForm()
   }
```

});

Answer (score 0):

А если этой кнопке сделать `focus()`? Тогда при нажатии `enter` будет нажатие на эту кнопку.

Comment: неплохая идея но я уже сделал при помощи keyup jquery